# Mysql: Count wins but only once per opponent

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for help using sum() in my SQL query:

Task: Count tournament wins of all players. (one number per player) (battles.result = 1 means Player1 wins)

```
SELECT members.id, members.name,
            (
                SELECT SUM(battles.result = 1)
                FROM battles
                WHERE members.id = battles.player1 AND battles.result=1 order by battles.gametime
            (   as wins,
FROM members
```

Next: Only count ONE result per two players.

So if there are multiple results of two players, count only the first result (first gametime).

I've already tried using order by battles.player2, but i guess there is a much better solution?

Comment: Provide the table structures and some example data as ascii data table.. Also post a ascii based data table showing the excepted results.. We are not here to reverse engineer your SQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get the result by doing a [join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) and [aggregation](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) instead. Try:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, SUM(IFNULL(B.result,0)) wons
FROM members A LEFT JOIN battles B
ON A.id=B.player1
GROUP BY  A.id, A.name;
```